# How are people handling pagination with DataSnap XE on a web client?

Tags: delphi, pagination, datasnap

I'm using jQuery Mobile to pull back some data into a list view.  I need to paginate this and can't seem to get table filters (url/class/function/?t.r1,20) to work.

I think I read XE will not do extra url parameters (XE2) does so I can't do my own ?page=2 stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK pagination works fine in both XE and XE2, but I think the syntax is not:

> /?t.r1,20

but slightly different, like:

?t.r=1,20

This is a javascript snippet that does the call using the client side support (the executor.js) to call GetCustomers asking for the page number "page", where pages are 3 records each:

```
var methExec = serverMethods().executor;
res = methExec.executeMethod("GetCustomers", 
  "GET", [], null, true, {"t.r": (page*3+1 + ",3")}, null);
res = res.result[0];
```

Otherwise simply create the proper URL manually.

Comment: Do I have to do anything with the server method to get this working?

Comment: My problem was trying to use the Table filter for a TJSONOBject response.  Table filters seem to only work on TDataSet return types, which are far too verbose for my needs.  Looks like I have to write my own filter.

Comment: No, there is nothing you have to do. But it works only on strings and tables. No objects or arrays.